# sql: like with wildcard

Tags: sql

I have a field in the database called `workdir` and data looks like this

```
/home/public/users/james/PB_3594162_hwkk8529_3594148_1601131530
```

i did

```
select workdur from work where workdur like '*PB_*';
```

but it doesn't seem to work

any idea what sql should be so i can get any workdur which has PB_?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: `*` is accepted as a wildcard in MS Access.  The ANSI standard -- used by all other databases -- is `%`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, try to use % instead of *.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, so others may benefit from it (if they search something like this post).

Answer (score 0):

Use % instead of *.

You can use wildcard % in below flavours.
1. String starts with wildcard and ends with sub string - '%YZ'
2. Strings end with wildcard and star with sub string - ''AB%'
3. String contains some sub string - '%NM%'